# Why email verification still present even the email is verified?

Tags: android, firebase, email, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing a mobile app as my final semester project. In my mobile app, I have this email verification using firebase authentication. Here's the tutorial I followed to do this function (if you're interested).

[Firebase Login & Register App With Email | Part - 8 | Verify Email Address](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pjmt5L3Y3o4&list=PLlGT4GXi8_8dm7OeLB5SiVZAPXeSq9i2Z&index=9)

My problem here is when I added the reset password function (the next part of the tutorial) in my mobile app, the email verification alert is still present even though the email is verified.

SETTINGS Activity (where the reset password and email verification function found)

```
package com.example.biowit;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

Button Back_ST_btn, AboutUs_btn, VerEmail_btn, Res_Pass_btn, Con_Res_btn, Cancel_Res_btn;
TextView VerEmail_txt;
EditText NewPass_input, CoNewPass_input;
FirebaseAuth set_FbAuth;
FirebaseUser set_FbUser;
String respass_set, conpass_set;
// Switch Music_swch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    AboutUs_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_AboutUs);
    Back_ST_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_ST_Back);
    Res_Pass_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_Reset_Pass);
    Con_Res_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_Confirm_Reset);
    Cancel_Res_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancel_Reset);
    NewPass_input = findViewById(R.id.txt_New_Pass);
    CoNewPass_input = findViewById(R.id.txt_CoNew_Pass);
    VerEmail_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_Verify_Email);
    VerEmail_txt = findViewById(R.id.lbl_Verify_Email);
    // Music_swch = findViewById(R.id.swch_ST_Music);.
    
    set_FbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    set_FbUser = set_FbAuth.getCurrentUser();


    Res_Pass_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            NewPass_input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            CoNewPass_input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Con_Res_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Cancel_Res_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    Cancel_Res_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NewPass_input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            CoNewPass_input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Con_Res_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Cancel_Res_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    Con_Res_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            respass_set = NewPass_input.getText().toString();
            conpass_set = CoNewPass_input.getText().toString();

            if(respass_set.isEmpty()){ // condition if new password field is empty, error message will be shown.
                NewPass_input.setError("This field cannot be empty.");
                return;
            }

            if(conpass_set.isEmpty()){ // condition if confirm password field is empty, error message will be shown.
                CoNewPass_input.setError("This field cannot be empty.");
                return;
            }

            if (!conpass_set.equals(respass_set)){ // condition if the confirm password is not equals to new password, error message will be shown.
                CoNewPass_input.setError("Password does not match.");
                return;
            }

            set_FbUser.updatePassword(respass_set).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"New Password saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    NewPass_input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    CoNewPass_input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Con_Res_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    //When email is not verified, a message and button will appear.
    if (!set_FbAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()){

        VerEmail_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        VerEmail_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    //When the "Verify Now" button is clicked, it will send a verification email to the user's email address.
    VerEmail_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //send verificaiton email
            set_FbAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Verification Email sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VerEmail_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    VerEmail_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    
    Back_ST_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // returns to previous screen.

            finish();
        }
    });

    AboutUs_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutUsScreen.class));
        }
    });
}

public void PlayBackgroundSound(View view){

    startService(new Intent(this, BgMusicService.class));
}

}
```

Here's the ERROR LOG

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.biowit, PID: 7789
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.biowit/com.example.biowit.HomeScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.biowit/.BgMusicService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{964c600 u0a2 TPSL idle change:cached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3754)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3912)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2319)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:239)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.biowit/.BgMusicService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{964c600 u0a2 TPSL idle change:cached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1758)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1698)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:720)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:720)
    at com.example.biowit.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8119)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8103)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1359)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3727)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3912) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2319) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:239) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1016) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:53820', transport: 'socket'
```

HERE'S THE PIC IN THE SETTINGS

The email that I used here to log - in is already verified before adding the reset password function.

As you can see, the email verification alert is present.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The User object is cached, this includes the Verified information. because of this, you will need to inform the client of the changes, with java this is done with a task

> WIth a sendEmailVerification() method, which returns as Task used to asynchronously send the email, and report on the status.

for Example:

```java
final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        user.sendEmailVerification()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        // Re-enable button
                        findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setEnabled(true);

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this,
                                    "Verification email sent to " + user.getEmail(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "sendEmailVerification", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this,
                                    "Failed to send verification email.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The user is retrieved from mAuth.getCurrentUser(), and the sendEmailVerification() method is called on it.

You can find a full guide here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/email-verification-in-firebase-auth.html